# PostgreSQL: A window with all records of a month, plus the last record of the priv month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with update requests for disk quotas. Each record has a request time, a path and as quota size.
I need to aggregate all request for a certain path in a cretain month, plus the last request of the priv month. Something like

> sum(quota) over (partition by )

I would appreciate some ideas or thoughts about how to do that in the most elegant way. Of course, it may be (and probably is) a multy-phase process.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is short on details. To give complete answer you need to supply table definition (ddl), test data (or better a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)), and the expected results of that data. However, retrieving this month's data and the latest form the prior month becomes something like:

```
select sq.path, sum(sq.quota) over (partition by sq.path) total_quota
  from ( select s.path, s.quota 
           from some_table s 
          where s.path = 'certain path'
            and date_trunc('month', s.request_time) = date_trunc('month', current_date) 
        union all  
        select sc.path, sc.quota 
           from some_table sc  
          where sc.path = 'certain path'
            and (sc.path,sc.request_time) = 
                (select sl.path, max(sl.request_time) 
                   from some_table sl
                  where sl.path = sc.path
                    and date_trunc('month', sl.request_time) = date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1 month')
                  group by sl.path
                ) sq1
       ) sq;
```

If the month of interest does not contain `current_date` you could pass a parameter value for the month of interest.

Note: this is not tested.